# is it possible recording through the 3.5mm headphone jack in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, microphone, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am making an app and i have created a functionality to record voice with iPhone but recording is not possible with 3.5mm headphone jack, its only working with iPhone mic. So please Suggest me what should i do.

My Recording code is:

```
-(void)recording
{
    [recordBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSLog(@"startRecording");

    inc_Bar=0.0;

    // [self performSelector:@selector(stopRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0f];

    [self increaseProgressBar];
    progressBarTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:recordingLength/1000.0f target:self selector:@selector(increaseProgressBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    audioRecorder = nil;

    // Init audio with record capability
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    if(recordEncoding == ENC_PCM)
    {
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sampleRateFloat] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
    }
    else
    {
        NSNumber *formatObject;

        switch (recordEncoding) {
            case (ENC_AAC):
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC];
                break;
            case (ENC_ALAC):
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless];
                break;
            case (ENC_IMA4):
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
                break;
            case (ENC_ILBC):
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatiLBC];
                break;
            case (ENC_ULAW):
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatULaw];
                break;
            default:
                formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4];
        }

        [recordSettings setObject:formatObject forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sampleRateFloat] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
//      [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *recDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recordTest.caf", recDir]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings error:&error];

    if ([audioRecorder prepareToRecord] == YES){
        [audioRecorder record];
    }else {
        int errorCode = CFSwapInt32HostToBig ([error code]);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ [%4.4s])" , [error localizedDescription], (char*)&errorCode);
    }
    NSLog(@"recording");
}
```

Thanks. Please Help.

Comment: So you want to record using hardware with no mic?

Comment: yes i want to record using both hardware and mic .

Comment: Ah, I think I've misunderstood your question; it doesn't work with the headphone + mic combo, only the built-in mic.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it's not recording through the 3.5mm headphone jack - it's just recording through the in built microphone.

Comment: Have you tried to use `setPreferredDataSource` to select the headphones as recording input?

Comment: No, Please suggest me , How can we use it.

Answer (score 0):

[Based on documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

> If a headset is plugged in at the time you set this property’s value tokAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker, the system changes the audio routing for input as well as for output: input comes from the built-in microphone; output goes to the built-in speaker.